# Converting int list into base64

Tags: python, list, base64

my steps are to :
1. Convert ASCII code into octets

2. Convert octets into sextets

3. Convert sextets into decimals

4. Convert decimals to their equivalent characters in base64 character index table

My problem is that I'm getting different output.

My input is "And"
Insted of "QW5K"
I'm getting "EBY5JA=="

```
import base64
asciiinput= input("Input Text: ")

bin = [ord(character) for character in asciiinput]
print("input to ascii value: ", bin)


octet = (''.join(map('{:08b}'.format, bin)))
print("Ascii to Octet: ",octet)

ls = list(octet)

test_list = list(map(int, ls))

n = 6
xs = [test_list[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(ls), n)]
print ("Octets to Sextets  : ",xs)


out = [int(''.join([str(y) for y in x]), 2) for x in xs]
print("Sextets into Decimals: ", out)

base64_code = base64.b64encode(bytes(out))
print(base64_code)
```

Comment: I have no idea what all those intermediate steps are supposed to be doing, you seem to just want `base64.b64encode(b"And")`.

Comment: Also, `out` is not a list of "decimals", it is a list of *`int` objects*.

Comment: @Makuchi your steps are all correct if you're trying to manually encode into base64, however `base64.b64encode` is not a base64 character index table, it's a library that does the encoding for you. You could easily create one yourself in the form of a `dict`. That being said, you should just hand your input directly to the library like the other answers are saying if this is anything other than a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it entirely with the `base64` module.

```py
import base64
asciiinput = input("Input Text: ")
base64_str = base64.b64encode(asciiinput.encode()).decode()
print(base64_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

`base64.b64encode(b"And")` gives `b'QW5k'`